# Grails 2.3 could not create jvm error

Tags: java, grails

I recently upgraded my grails application from grails 1.3.6 to grails 2.3. Up-gradation process completed successfully with required changes. 
Now i'm facing a problem please see stack-trace:

> ```
> | Running Grails application
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
> | Error Forked Grails VM exited with error`
> ```
>
> Any help??
>   Thanks

Comment: I'm using STS 3.2 IDE, grails 2.3 and groovy 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running a 32bit version of the JVM, which will only support a max heap size of 2 gigabytes, not 4 gigabytes.

Find out what version of the JDK / JRE Grails is using.  Then see whether you can change it to a 64 bit VM if you need 4 gigs of heap space.  Otherwise, amend your startup parameters so that the JVM only requests a 2 gig heap size when Grails spawns it.

Comment: Thanks, i'm using 32bit version JVM, i made following changes to BuildConfig.groovy for startup :
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ["-Xmx2048m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"]
now grails> run-app working fine but it will not release jvm while i try to stop my app.